# Laravel carbon get current month in dutch

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm trying to show the full current month name in dutch. I've tried it like this:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth()->format('F')
```

But then I see `July` so not what I want. My app service
provider looks like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    Carbon::setLocale('nl');
}
```

Any Idea what I could do to get this to work?

(diffForHumans is working correctly)

Comment: What you want as result ?

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo I want the dutch translation of a month. So instead of ```July``` I want ```Juni```.

Comment: Not sure about this issue sorry, but I know of a good alternative package - which is based on Carbon, if you were interested: https://github.com/jenssegers/date

Comment: @AareonFahey thanks that solved my problem!

Comment: @AareonFahey but it's not good I guess to pull in an entire package only to fix this :)

Comment: Other sources seem to suggest that you can also try `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nl');` in your service provider.

Comment: @Jamie Not sure where you are from, but the Dutch translation for July is 'juli' not 'juni'

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to pull an entire package and want to only install your locale, then you could list the locale installed in your `(linux)` server by issuing the command

```
locale -a
```

If your locale isn't listed, then you may install your locale `nl` using the command

```
sudo locale-gen nl
sudo update-locale
```

then the usual `setLocale`

Answer (score 2):

Just check [class.intldateformatter.php](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php)

And try this

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'nl_NL',
     IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
     IntlDateFormatter::NONE
);
echo $fmt->format(mktime(null, null, null, 1, 15, 2014));

// output: 15 januari 2014
```